# Where are network interfaces generated from in VirtualBox?

Tags: networking, windows-10, virtualbox

currently I have a Windows 10, Virtualbox 5.20 setup and some old / unwanted network interfaces shown by VirtualBox.

If I look into my current VirtualBox setup under "Bridged networking" i find the following interfaces:

[image: VirtualBox list of interfaces]

there are some interfaces I used years ago on my system but I can't find anywhere remaining in the system. Do you have an Idea where I could find them and remove then from the system?

Some other information about the devices:

List of interfaces from NetworkInterafeView:

[image: NetworkInterfaceView (NirSoft)]

List of interfaces from Windows:

[image: Windows networkinterfaces]

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: those are adapters, not software Interfaces. Its a subtle distinction, but meaningful nonetheless in troubleshooting your problem.

Comment: Have you checked in Device Manager under "Network Adapters"?  You should be able to uninstall adapter drivers from there.

Comment: @heavyd: Yes, I did. Even enabled the option to show hidden and disabled devices. There are no devices other than my "normal" network card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a solution as posted in https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=82574&hilit=bridgedif&start=15#p396149:

My old network adapters were stored in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkSetup2\Interfaces\` where my admin account didn't have access. It is only limited to `NetSetupSvc`and `TrustedInstaller`.

So I downloaded **[RunAsTI](https://github.com/jschicht/RunAsTI)**, started `regedit.exe`, went to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkSetup2\Interfaces\` and deleted them by their GUID I got from `VBoxManage.exe list bridgedifs`.

After that they are gone and I can sleep deep and well again ;).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I had a completely different issue where my WiFi stopped working, I ran "netconfig -d" which deleted my adapters and then they ceased to return, even though they showed in event manager.  This pointed me in the correct direction--I cleaned out the Interfaces key, rebooted, and BAM, everything was working properly.  THANK YOU!